# Real analysis help: Proof of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

The question is:
Let $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $h(m/2^n)=0$ for all $m\in \mathbb{Z},n\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $h(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

My attempt: Suppose that there exists $x$ such that $h(x)\neq0$. Then, since $h$ is continuous, given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $\vert{x-c}\vert<\delta$, then $\vert{h(x)-h(c)}\vert<\epsilon$.

I have no clue of what to do next. Can somebody give me a continued solution or any other solution to this question? Thank you.

Comment: Note the set $\{ m/2^n : m\in\Bbb Z, n\in \Bbb N\}$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. (So, you can find a number of the form $m/2^n$ as close as you like to $x$; so close, in fact, that $|f(m/2^n)|>|h(x)/2|$.)

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you for your comment. But I quite don't understand the inequality you wrote there. I know that whenever $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$, there is always a number $m/2^n$ between $a$ and $b$. But how does being dense relate to the number being really close to $x$ and where did the function $f$ come from? Could you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: Sorry. That "$f$" should be an "$h$".

Comment: Wonderful! Another question.. Is the set being dense equivalent to saying that there is a number of the form $m/2^n$ really really close to $x$? How do you know the fact that the number is really close to $x$?

Comment: Given $x$ and any $n$, $x$ lies in some interval of the form $[m/2^n, (m+1)/2^n)$. The length of this interval is $1/2^n$, which  can be made as small as you like by taking $n$ sufficiently large. It follows that the distance between $x$ and an endpoint of the interval is less than $1/2^n$.

Comment: Okay. I understand the intuition. So there is a $x$ s.t. $m/2^n<x$ So $\vert{x-m/2^n}\vert$ can be made extremely small and because $h$ is continuous, this implies that $\vert{h(x)-h(m/2^n)}\vert$ is made small as well. But isn't it that $\vert{h(m/2^n)}\vert<\vert{h(x)}\vert?$ How do you get the $\vert{h(m/2^n)}\vert<\vert{h(x)/2}\vert$? Sorry I'm asking a lot of questions..

Comment: The inequality goes the other way: $|h(m/2^n)|>|h(x)/2|$. In the definition of continuity at $x$, just choose $\epsilon=|h(x)/2|$. Note $|h(x)-h(m/2^n)|<\epsilon$ implies the inequality (perhaps draw a picture here for the two cases $h(x)<0$ and $h(x)>0$). Your proof starts off with "assume $h(x)\ne0$"; you can then deduce that there is an $m/2^n$ with $h(m/2^n)\ne 0$. This proves the contrapositive statement.

Comment: So $\epsilon$ being $\vert{h(x)}\vert/2$ is just an arbitrary value? so can we choose something like $\epsilon=\vert{h(x)}\vert/100$?

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot!

Comment: You're welcome; glad to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any $\epsilon > 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ find $m$ and $n$ such that $|x - \frac{m}{2^n}| < \delta$ where $\delta$ corresponds to $\epsilon$ is the definition of continuity of $f$. Thus $|f(x) - f(\frac{m}{2^n})| = |f(x)| < \epsilon$ and it follows $f(x) = 0$. You should argue why such an $m$ and $n$ exist.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Though, how did you go from $\vert{f(x)}\vert<\epsilon$ to get $f(x)=0$?

Comment: We have shown $|f(x)|< \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon >0$. Then $|f(x)|=0$ because 0 is the only nonnegative real number less than any positive $\epsilon$.